# What's the mathematics definition of the F value in Analysis of Variance Table?

Tags: r, regression, anova

Suppose I have a linear regression model Y ~ b1*x1 + b2*x2 with the sample data:

```
        x1      x2        y
0  -0.7251 -0.6033  10.2508
1  -1.3148  3.7067  10.3054
2  -1.2818 -5.8136   7.2010
3   0.6154  3.6336  11.2807
4   1.4887 -2.8337  10.6299
5  -2.0224 -0.3931   7.4502
6   0.5419 -1.7807  10.7339
7  -1.0745 -5.0296   5.8734
8   3.2116 -0.4681  11.7184
9   1.6767 -4.6040   9.0145
10 -1.3355 -2.6874   6.5014
11  0.8296  2.6793  11.8295
12 -2.8647  4.2916   7.8414
13  1.8445 -3.3924   9.6520
14 -0.1036  2.4273  11.9766
15  1.0886 -3.5636  10.6023
16 -3.3026 -6.9837   4.9962
17  1.4050 -3.8453  10.4630
18 -0.3111 -1.4278   9.2283
19 -3.5454  2.4960   7.3720
```

And using the following R code to get the Analysis of Variance Table:

```
> df <- read.csv('f:/data.csv', header=T, sep=",")
> model_All <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=df)
> anova(model_All)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
x1         1 44.440  44.440  58.277 6.865e-07 ***
x2         1 26.640  26.640  34.934 1.711e-05 ***
Residuals 17 12.964   0.763                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And I can calculate the F value of hypothesis test H0： b2=0 via:

```
> model_Drop2 <- lm(y ~ x1, data=df)
> SSR_All = sum(resid(model_All)^2)
> SSR_Dp2 = sum(resid(model_Drop2)^2)
> F_x2 = ((SSR_Dp2 - SSR_All) / 1) / (SSR_All / (20 - 3))
> F_x2
[1] 34.93434
```

We can see that `F_x2` **is equal to** F value of `x2` in `Analysis of Variance Table`.
However, the value `F_x1` calculated as follow **is not equal to** F value of `x1`, I can't understand why:

```
> model_Drop1 <- lm(y ~ x2, data=df)
> SSR_Dp1 = sum(resid(model_Drop1)^2)
> F_x1 = ((SSR_Dp1 - SSR_All) / 1) / (SSR_All / (20 - 3))
> F_x1
[1] 70.30392
```

So, what is the mathematics definition of the F value in table?

**EDIT** The result of the features reversed as commented by @Michael M:

```
> model_All2 <- lm(y ~ x2 + x1, data=df)
> anova(model_All2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
x2         1 17.468  17.468  22.907 0.0001718 ***
x1         1 53.612  53.612  70.304 1.914e-07 ***
Residuals 17 12.964   0.763                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Check the output using "model_All2 <- lm(y ~ x2 + x1, data=df)" instead, so with reversed features. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of variables you declare matters when creating this ANOVA table. To see how the table is constructed:

In general, as you move down a row, you consider an incrementally more complex model. So the row labelled by `x1` considers the difference between the model `y~x1` and `y~1`. The row labelled by `x2` considers the difference between the model `y~x1+x2` and `y~x1`. The residual row considers the difference between the full model and the actual observations.

Now let's go column by column:

The `Df` column is the degrees of freedom, which you already seem to know.

The `Sum Sq` column looks at the difference between the SSR of the two models that the row compares. So for `x1` this is the SSR of the `y~1` model (let's call this `SRR_Nul`) and `SSR_Dp2`.

The `Mean Sq` column is the `Sum Sq` column divided by the `Df` column. This is like saying how much model improvement is made per sacrificed degree of freedom.

The `F value` column is the `Sum Sq` value divided by the overall model mean residual sum of square, in the final row of the previous column.

So, if you want to manually calculate the F value of the `x1` row, you would need to calculate:

```r
> F_x1 = ((SSR_Nul-SSR_Dp2) / 1) / (SSR_All / (20 - 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to understand here is that the order in which the variables enter the model matters, unless they are orthogonal. This is the reason the anova table does not agree with your partial F-test, in the latter the variable $x_2$ is already in the model!