# What is the mathematics definition of the F value in the ANOVA table?

Tags: r, regression, anova

Suppose I have a linear regression model Y ~ b1*x1 + b2*x2 with the sample data:

```
        x1      x2        y
0  -0.7251 -0.6033  10.2508
1  -1.3148  3.7067  10.3054
2  -1.2818 -5.8136   7.2010
3   0.6154  3.6336  11.2807
4   1.4887 -2.8337  10.6299
5  -2.0224 -0.3931   7.4502
6   0.5419 -1.7807  10.7339
7  -1.0745 -5.0296   5.8734
8   3.2116 -0.4681  11.7184
9   1.6767 -4.6040   9.0145
10 -1.3355 -2.6874   6.5014
11  0.8296  2.6793  11.8295
12 -2.8647  4.2916   7.8414
13  1.8445 -3.3924   9.6520
14 -0.1036  2.4273  11.9766
15  1.0886 -3.5636  10.6023
16 -3.3026 -6.9837   4.9962
17  1.4050 -3.8453  10.4630
18 -0.3111 -1.4278   9.2283
19 -3.5454  2.4960   7.3720
```

And using the following R code to get the Analysis of Variance Table:

```
> df <- read.csv('f:/data.csv', header=T, sep=",")
> model_All <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=df)
> anova(model_All)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
x1         1 44.440  44.440  58.277 6.865e-07 ***
x2         1 26.640  26.640  34.934 1.711e-05 ***
Residuals 17 12.964   0.763                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And I can calculate the F value of hypothesis test H0： b2=0 via:

```
> model_Drop2 <- lm(y ~ x1, data=df)
> SSR_All = sum(resid(model_All)^2)
> SSR_Dp2 = sum(resid(model_Drop2)^2)
> F_x2 = ((SSR_Dp2 - SSR_All) / 1) / (SSR_All / (20 - 3))
> F_x2
[1] 34.93434
```

We can see that `F_x2` **is equal to** F value of `x2` in `Analysis of Variance Table`.
However, the value `F_x1` calculated as follow **is not equal to** F value of `x1`, I can't understand why:

```
> model_Drop1 <- lm(y ~ x2, data=df)
> SSR_Dp1 = sum(resid(model_Drop1)^2)
> F_x1 = ((SSR_Dp1 - SSR_All) / 1) / (SSR_All / (20 - 3))
> F_x1
[1] 70.30392
```

So, what is the mathematics definition of the F value in table?

Comment: Already answered, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173026/whats-the-mathematics-definition-of-the-f-value-in-analysis-of-variance-table